# Is it possible to query/download satellite images with Python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, google-maps, image, satellite

I was wondering if there exists a Python library/API for downloading satellite images. Ideally, I would want to enter the latitude and longitude of a bounding box and get a high resolution image covering that box. Whether it is from Google Maps or other services doesn't matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: OpenStreetMap doesn't have satellite imagery. You may wish to start you search here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363257/how-to-automate-satellite-image-downloads

Comment: Do you actually want to download the data, or is a WMS a suitable option?

Comment: Just downloading. @GIS-Jonathan, fixed that.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/landsat-util/ for Landsat imagery 2015/2016 source comes from http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/

Comment: https://github.com/ibamacsr/sentinelsat for Copernicus Sentinel images. Disclaimer: I contribute to this project.

Comment: Google Earth Engine has a Python API. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install

Comment: There's also the [Planet Labs API](https://github.com/planetlabs/planet-client-python) to download data from their doves.

Answer (score 4):

There are python APIs for downloading satellite imagery. You can get one from any of:- 
1) www.planet.com
2) www.openstreetmap.org

This pycon presentation "Python from Space: Analyzing Open Satellite Imagery Using the Python Ecosystem" by Katherine Scott covers what you are looking for. See details of it at: https://github.com/kscottz/PythonFromSpace/blob/master/README.md

Also these OS questions has some useful answers related to what you are looking for: 
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802513/where-how-to-get-free-high-resolution-satellite-images-for-geospatial-data-vis
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490491/capture-embedded-google-map-image-with-python-without-using-a-browser

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this https://github.com/Jimut123/jimutmap. I have created a scraper to download any amount of map tiles by which you can create any amount of map data for training in Deep Neural Network architectures. Since this uses the Haversine formula for indexing the map tiles, you can download map tiles at any scale by passing a parameter known as zoom. You can also download large quantities of maps through multi-threading within seconds, so this is the best place for scraping any map place within seconds. You can even get road masks by modifying the code, so in essence you get everything for free.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over a year but in case someone is still wondering, you can also try this github repo that worked for me: https://github.com/thewati/ExtractSatelliteImagesFromCSV